# Numpy 3D matrix multiplication

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I have 2 matrices A(shape 10x10x36) and B(shape 10x27x36). I would like to multiply the last 2 axes and sum the result along axis 0 so that the result C is of the shape 10x27. Here is currently how I do it

```
C = []
for i in range(A.shape[0]):
    C.append(np.matmul(A[i], B[i].T))
C = np.sum(np.array(C), axis=0)
```

I want to achieve this in a vectorized manner but can't seem to find out how. I have checked out [np.einsum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) but not yet sure how to apply it to achieve the result. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`matmul` supports stacking. You can simply do:

```
 (A@B.transpose(0,2,1)).sum(0)
```

Checks (`C` is generated using OP's loop):

```
np.allclose((A@B.transpose(0,2,1)).sum(0),C)
# True
timeit(lambda:(A@B.transpose(0,2,1)).sum(0),number=1000)
# 0.03199950899579562
# twice as fast as original loop
```

Answer (score 3):

Here the same result using `np.einsum`:

```
r1 = np.einsum('ijk,ilk->jl', A, B)
```

However in my machine the for loop implementation runs almost 2x faster:

```
def f(A,B):
    C = []
    for i in range(A.shape[0]):
        C.append(np.matmul(A[i], B[i].T))
    return np.sum(np.array(C), axis=0)

%timeit np.einsum('ijk,ilk->jl',A,B)
102 µs ± 3.79 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit f(A,B)
57.6 µs ± 1.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: Great solution too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could also try the following using list comprehension. It's a bit more concise than what you are currently using.

```
C=np.array([A[i] @ B.T[:,:,i] for i in range(10)]).sum(0)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it still involves a native Python list so the only difference from my original code is the syntax